# Two databases merging into Solr - How to keep uniqueID for entries?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, solr

I have two databases (unfortunatly they do have to be separate) which get imported into Solr.

Each database has a primary key for each time but I am concerned that when it comes to importing the two into SOLR there will be more than one item with the same ID (one from each DB).

Therefore, in order to keep two seperate databases with two different uniqueIDs, I was wondering what kind of options I have.

Should I append a letter to the primary key of one DB. Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you describe your import process a little bit?

Comment: Sure. There is something called the DIH (delta import handler) and in there I specify the details of all the sources I want to import. In my case I have two seperate databases.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Solr, does it store items in a table or as objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ensure you do not have an ID conflict you can create a new id which will act as Unique key for Solr.

The DIH sqls can be configured as :-

e.g.

```
SELECT 'TABLE1' || ID AS PRIMARY_ID ... FROM TABLE1
SELECT 'TABLE2' || ID AS PRIMARY_ID ... FROM TABLE2
```

In Solr the unique key would be PRIMARY_ID instead of the table ID.
This will ensure you will always have a unique key even if the table's Id conflict.

Comment: Sorry to be akward, but I want the DB_ID to match the SOLR_ID because that is the only way I can use my database record to update solr.

Comment: Would it work to start the UniqueID of one of the databases starting with a letter, or perhaps starting with a "0"?

Comment: You can still use the Solr Id to update the records as the delta queries would have the same configuration as the main query.